# Can't populate integer value in title field using rules

Tags: rules

I have a integer value that I'm trying to add to the title of a new node, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

This the rule I have so far.

```
{ "rules_rule_create_bid" : {
"LABEL" : "Create a new Bid",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "button_field", "rules", "path" ],
"ON" : { "button_field_clicked" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "button_field_compare_button" : {
      "clicked_field" : [ "field" ],
      "comparison_field_name" : "field_email_client"
    }
  },
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "entity" ], "field" : "field_client_email" } },
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "entity" ], "field" : "field_project_id2" } },
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "entity" ], "field" : "field_bid_count" } },
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "entity" ], "field" : "body" } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "entity_create" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "node",
        "param_type" : "new_bid",
        "param_title" : "Default",
        "param_author" : [ "site:current-user" ]
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:field-bid-contractorname" ],
      "value" : "[site:current-user]"
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:field-bid-projectid" ],
      "value" : [ "entity:field-project-id2" ]
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:field-project-description" ],
      "value" : [ "entity:body:value" ]
    }
  },
  { "node_path_alias" : {
      "node" : [ "entity-created" ],
      "alias" : "p_[entity-created:field-bid-projectid]_u_[site:current-user]"
    }
  },
  { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-created" ], "immediate" : "1" } },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:title" ],
      "value" : "New Project #[entity-created:field-project-id2]"
    }
  },
  { "redirect" : { "url" : "p_[entity-created:field-bid-projectid]_u_[site:current-user]#overlay=node\/[entity-created:nid]\/edit" } },
  { "drupal_message" : { "message" : [ "entity:field-client-email" ] } }
]
}
}
```

I want the entity:field_project_id to show in the title, but all I get is the project number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title is a string, that's why, in your rule, before setting title value, add a variable, then set variable value to the integer value, then add an action: "convert a data type": your variable, from integer to string, then set a data value, your node title as variable name. else leave the same as it is.